# What sanity checks to apply to reduced-form VAR model

Tags: autoregressive, var

When you build a vector autoregressive (VAR) model with macroeconomic variables, what sanity checks do you apply before identification?

How do you ensure that the estimation/coefficients are reasonable? What statistics should one look at before identification?